# Unresolved Webapp Library references while deploying ADF Application

Tags: java, deployment, oracle-adf, weblogic-10.x

I have following Versions for developing and Implementing ADF Application

`Jdeveloper Studio Edition Version 11.1.2.4.0
Weblogic  10.3.6.0
ADF Run Time 11.1.1.9.0`

Below is my Weblogic.xml Setting

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.1/weblogic-web-app.xsd" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <context-root>FlashDB</context-root>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>adf.oracle.domain.webapp</library-name>
    </library-ref>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jstl</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.2</specification-version>
    </library-ref>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jsf</library-name>
        <specification-version>2.0</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.2</implementation-version>
         <exact-match>false</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

When i am deploying ADF Application from Jdeveloper i got below error on Weblogic Console

```
<Dec 19, 2017 8:22:13 PM PKT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for applicati
on 'FlashDB_Project1_FlashDB'.>
<Dec 19, 2017 8:22:13 PM PKT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'FlashDB'
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:180)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:518)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.management.DeploymentException: Error: Unresolved Webapp Library references for "ServletContext@54465674[app:F
lashDB_Project1_FlashDB module:FlashDB path:/FlashDB spec-version:2.5]", defined in weblogic.xml [Extension-Name: jsf, Specificati
on-Version: 2, exact-match: false]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processWebAppLibraries(WebAppServletContext.java:2750)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:416)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any Can help what exactly is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the wrong runtime version of ADF with the version you developed.
Your JDeveloper version should match your ADF Runtime version - both should be 11.1.2.4 in your case.
Also 11.1.2.4 is quite old - better upgrade to 12c

Comment: can you please tell me if i still want to use jdeveloper 11.1.2.4 then which version of adf runtime is supported with weblogic 10.3.6

Comment: Get ADF 11.1.2.4 - this is no longer on OTN - but if you are a supported customer you should be able to get it from edelivery.oracle.com http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/jdev11gr2-cert-405181.html